# Basset 4 (pre-beta)

Tags: laravel

I'm using Basset 4 to manage assets.

In the config file i'm declaring a collection 'admin'

```
return array(



'collections' => array(
    'admin' => function($collection)
    {
        $collection->directory('assets/js', function($collection)
        {
           $collection->add('vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js');
        });
    },
),

...
)
```

later in a view, I would like to add an extra file in admin collection.

I've try the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
Basset::collection('admin', function($collection)
{
   $collection->add('function.js');
});
```

Is there a way to add file into a collection from a view or from a controller?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basset isn't *really* designed to work like that. You should be defining all your assets within that initial call, even though the ability to add assets throughout the execution of an application is possible, it's not recommended.

1. When building a collection assets that are added for a particular route won't be available to the builder since Artisan doesn't fire any routes, etc.
2. Adjusting a collection in numerous places can often lead to confusion further down the line.

I know this isn't ideal as you're probably looking at implementing page specific JavaScript, correct? I've thought about it but can't really think of a clean solution (suggestions?), although I've heard of people assigning a unique ID to the body or perhaps some classes that their JavaScript can then attach themselves to.

It's not brilliant but that's the best I can give you at the moment.